# React await promise resolve not getting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

I am using `async/await` in the following function

```
forgotPassword = async ({ variables }) => {
    console.log(variables)
    const url = `//url constructed`
    console.log(url)
    try {
      const result: any = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          mode: 'no-cors'
        }
      })

      console.log('result fetched is -->', result)

      return {
        data: {
          login: result.json()
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({
        error:
          err?.response?.data?.error_description || err.message || strings.genericError
      })
      throw err
    }
  }
```

So, In the result when I did

```
result.json()
```

i am getting response like :

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
Status: "Successful"
Time: "1619013232787"
__proto__: Object
```

so when I tried doing

```
const status = result?.Status
```

then it gave me `undefined`

How to get the response ? even the promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to await result.json() since it returns a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Body/json

```
 try {
      const result: any = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          mode: 'no-cors'
        }
      })
      const data = await result.json();
      return {data};
```